# Formik + Yup number validation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, formik, yup

Hello I am trying to use Formik + Yup to validate my form. I am stuck with validating the number for the date, but touching any field keeps crashing the app after I add the number field. How do I properly validate the min and max of a number with Yup?

See my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ly027lklq7

If you comment out the whole day date field, the app runs as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of object validation before accessing nested items in `touched` is causing the issue.

*Eg:*

```js
...
props.errors.address && props.errors.address.line1 && props.touched.address.line1
...
...
props.errors.dob && props.errors.dob.day && props.touched.dob.day
...
```

should be,

```js
...
props.errors.address && props.errors.address.line1 && props.touched.address && props.touched.address.line1
...
...
props.errors.dob && props.errors.dob.day && props.touched.dob && props.touched.dob.day
...
```

Existing validation is working fine.

fixed code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/2omxr4jopp

Comment: Thanks man! Seems a bit verbose to have to check all those values every time, but glad we got something working!

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key